# How do you pass parameters containing spaces in vbs

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, dos

I have a batch script:

#### test.bat

```
echo first arg is %1
pause
```

That I want to invoke from a vbscript with admin rights like so:

#### test.vbs

```
Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
UAC.ShellExecute "test.bat", "argument", "", "runas", 1
```

This works ok but I am unable to pass a path argument that contains spaces as a single argument. Basically, I need to enclose the argument in spaces but whatever I try, it doesn't work. It looks like it invokes the batch, but the cmd window just flashes up and disappears so I don't know what is going wrong.
I've tried:

```
UAC.ShellExecute "test.bat", """has spaces""", "", "runas", 1
```

and

```
UAC.ShellExecute "test.bat", Chr(34) & "has spaces" & Chr(34), "", "runas", 1
```

and

```
UAC.ShellExecute "test.bat", '"has spaces"', , "runas", 1
```

and

```
UAC.ShellExecute "cmd", "/c test.bat " & chr(34) & "has spaces" & chr(34), "", "runas", 1
```

But no luck. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure *why* that doesn't work but this should; `UAC.ShellExecute "cmd", "/c test.bat " & chr(34) & "has spaces" & chr(34), "", "runas", 1`

Comment: Odd, its working for me if I pass the full path; /c c:\temp\test.bat

Comment: Ah yes, me too, thanks! Very odd though, will investigate more...

Comment: passing cmd the args "/k test.bat " (/k keeps the window open) show me that it is running in \windows\system32 which is why the batch script was not found

Comment: Ah makes sense perhaps runas causes it to ignore the current directory of the executing user

Comment: @AlexK. : 
https://gist.github.com/3f66e47a56368155f920

the chr(34) trick doesn't work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to get this working is:

```
UAC.ShellExecute "cmd", "/c """"c:\test.bat"" ""has spaces""""", "", "runas", 1
```

The important thing to note when using runas to invoke admin user rights, is that the working directory will change to c:\windows\system32. Therefore, you need to specify the full path to the batch file so that it can be found.

I'm still not sure why this only works when passing the bat file as an argument to "cmd", rather than executing it directly.

All credit due to [Alex K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246342/alex-k), from the comments.

In this case you need to quote the entire set of arguments to cmd, and each of the arguments also. You also need to double up the quotes. It looks a bit mad, but this is the best solution because otherwise it will fail if you have a space in any arguments and the bat file path.